# Where can I find the value of cards from the Dragon Ball Z Trading Card Game?

Tags: pricing, dragon-ball-z-ccg

I've got a bunch of old Dragon Ball Z Trading Cards from 2000-2004 that I'm trying to find values of, but I can't seem to find anywhere that gives me prices for any of these old cards. Is there somewhere I can go to find old card prices?

I've found sites like [RetroDBZCCG](http://retrodbzccg.com/card-images/), but it only shows images not prices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options actually.

- [TCGPlayer](http://shop.tcgplayer.com/price-guide/dragon-ball-z-tcg/perfection): Will give you market price and median
- [Ebay](http://www.ebay.ca/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2050601.m570.l1313.TR12.TRC2.A0.H0.Xdbz%20tcg.TRS0&_nkw=dbz%20tcg&_sacat=0)  : Will give you what people are asking for the cards
- [AlternativeWorld](http://www.alternateworlds.com.au/catalogue_items/dragon-ball-z-card-and-price-lists): Seems a bit outdated, but it may help.

Hope this helps.

Edit: Also I noted that in your question you referred to it as CCG (Collectible Card Game). If you do your searches with TCG (Trading Card Game) it probably turns out more results.